# Clear selected value in angular-selectize

Tags: angularjs, selectize.js

I'm using angular-selectize in my Angular app and would like to clear the selected value.
I have a selectize that changes a different selectize which in turn shows nothing selected (because it remembers the last value being what it was and the new options don't have it).

I have this selectize:

```
<selectize placeholder='Select a product' options='productsNames' config="{maxItems: 1}" ng-model="choosenProduct" ng-change="fetchProduct(choosenProduct)"></selectize>
```

Which in turn changes the option in this selectize:

```
<selectize id="product-selection" placeholder='Select a product' options='productInstance' config="{maxItems: 1}" ng-model="choosenInstance"></selectize>
```

But when the options change the selectize turns into a box with a `1px` height.
Any help would be highly appreciated